# how to integrate user based permission and role based permission in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.4, roles, user-permissions

```
laravel version : 5.4 
Php verision : 5.6
```

I want to apply permission in my system role based and user based permission.

I can give role based permission. also i want to add one custom role where i can give user based permission , Means for this role two user can have different permission although they are in same group.

Comment: This is likely to be closed as too broad, but there are existing packages for handling this, such as Sentinel (https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0) - Supports a combo of group and user permissions.

Comment: @TimLewis   Thanks brother , let me try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the spatie permission in local 

1. 
    Removed : composer.lock and vender 
    Run     :

```
composer require spatie/laravel-permission:^1
```

2. 
    In Laravel 5.5 the service provider will automatically get registered.
     In older versions of the framework just add the service provider in config/app.php file:

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider::class,
];
```

3.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider" --tag="migrations"
```

4.

```
Run : php artisan migrate

Output : 
Migrating: 2018_09_14_114242_add_start_date_to_project_activity_table
Migrated:  2018_09_14_114242_add_start_date_to_project_activity_table
Migrating: 2018_09_14_115119_update_start_date_to_project_activity_table
Migrated:  2018_09_14_115119_update_start_date_to_project_activity_table
Migrating: 2018_09_20_065330_add_project_maintenance_ppa_id_to_project_maintenance_table
Migrated:  2018_09_20_065330_add_project_maintenance_ppa_id_to_project_maintenance_table
Migrating: 2018_09_21_053456_add_project_maintenance_contact_id_to_project_maintenance_table
Migrated:  2018_09_21_053456_add_project_maintenance_contact_id_to_project_maintenance_table
Migrating: 2018_09_24_051933_add_start_date_end_date_to_maintenance_resolution_table
Migrated:  2018_09_24_051933_add_start_date_end_date_to_maintenance_resolution_table
Migrating: 2018_09_28_061855_create_permission_tables
Migrated:  2018_09_28_061855_create_permission_tables
```

5.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider" --tag="config"
```